# wget - download the links that each of the webpage contains

Tags: linux, shell, wget

I'm studying wget and httrack. I am on the following difficulty:

I have a list of webpages and I'm trying to download the links that each of the webpage contains

For example, I have the list of webpages below and I want to download the content of the links that are inside each of them:

http://www.un.org/en/sc/documents/resolutions/2010.shtml
http://www.un.org/en/sc/documents/resolutions/2011.shtml

I've used the command:

```
wget -r -c -nd -l2 -n --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092416 Firefox/3.0.3" -erobots=off --no-check-certificate   -P .~/Documentos/teste -i un.txt
```

Can I use wget to download webpage links? Enter the indicated webpage, download the content linked in this webpage ... or only tools like selenium do this?

Best regards!

Comment: wget has a `-m` (mirror) flag, that should help :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.